# How do I get the size of a font in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

I have a NSString with it's attributes (a dictionary). I could get a NSAttributedString with this.
I need to know what's the size of the string.With the font I can only get the height, using capHeight method, but I need also the width, how do I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
NSSize size = [attrString size];
CGFloat width = size.width;
CGFloat height = size.height;
[attrString release];

NSLog(@"String width: %f", width);
NSLog(@"String height: %f", height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

```
- (NSRect)boundingRectWithSize:(NSSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options
```

on NSAttributedString